# TextView не помешается текст

Tags: android, textview, android-textview

При длинном тексте некоторые слова выходят за рамки. Как сделать, чтобы перенос был корректный? Длинный текст в taskView = "В комнате не работает gjjjjfghfhgfhfhgfhgfhggfh fhghfgfgf gfhyyfgh fhfffgh fgfhhf fhhf hghg." По словам переносит, но как то некорректно.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:background="@drawable/customborder">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rectangleNumber"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="28dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dateTimeView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/rectangleNumber"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/rectangleNumber" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/address"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_medium"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/dateTimeView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/dateTimeView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cvalView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_medium"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/address"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/address" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/taskView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_medium"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/cvalView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cvalView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/taskView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/taskView" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/agreeBtn"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
        android:backgroundTint="#00CC4F"
        android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
        android:text="Принять"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/description"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/description" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/disagreeBtn"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#F23B51"
        android:text="Отклонить"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
        android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/agreeBtn"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/agreeBtn" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если среди ответов есть правильный, то примите его, пожалуйста!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы **TextView** внутри **ConstraintLayout'a** корректно отображал длинные текста, необходимо сперва привязать данный компонент к родительским краям контейнера, либо к ближайшим соседним элементам, и выставить значение ширины в 0dp **android:layout_width="0dp**.

*Пример №1:*

```
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="Lorem Ipsum является текст-заполнитель обычно используется в графических, печать и издательской индустрии для предварительного просмотра макета и визуальных макетах." />
```

Есть еще такой вариант. В данном случае мы просто растягиваем ширину **TextView** на всю длину контейнера **android:layout_width="match_parent"**. Результат идентичный, текст прекрасно переходит на новую строку. Но такой трюк не пройдет если на одной строке вы решите поместить 2 компонента **TextView**.

*Пример №2*

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="Lorem Ipsum является текст-заполнитель обычно используется в графических, печать и издательской индустрии для предварительного просмотра макета и визуальных макетах." />
```

Дополнительно могу посоветовать использовать такие атрибуты как [**ellipsize**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:ellipsize) и [**maxLines**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:maxLines). Что позволит добавить многоточие в конце текста если текст длиннее заданного значения.

*Пример №3:*

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLines="2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:text="Lorem Ipsum является текст-заполнитель обычно используется в графических, печать и издательской индустрии для предварительного просмотра макета и визуальных макетах." />
```

*Решение вашей проблемы с приложенным скрином:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:padding="8dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rectangleNumber"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="28dp"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:background="#F59723"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/dateTimeView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="72877" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dateTimeView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/address"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/rectangleNumber"
        tools:text="2019-12-28 09:00" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/address"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/cvalView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/dateTimeView"
        tools:text="Lorem Ipsum" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cvalView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/taskView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/address"
        tools:text="Lorem Ipsum?" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/taskView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/description"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cvalView"
        tools:text="Lorem Ipsum! Это текст - рыба, часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне. Lorem Ipsum является стандартной рыбой для текстов на латинице с начала XVI века." />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/agreeBtn"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/taskView"
        tools:text="Это текст - рыба, часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне. Lorem Ipsum является стандартной рыбой для текстов на латинице с начала XVI века." />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/agreeBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#00CC4F"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/description"
        tools:text="Принять" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/disagreeBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="#F23B51"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/agreeBtn"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/agreeBtn"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/agreeBtn"
        tools:text="Отклонить" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: Демонстрация результат в превьюшке]

З.Ы. Предлагаю вам познакомится с компонентом **ConstraintLayout** чуть ближе в оф [доках](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout), плюс можете посмотреть видео по этому компоненту у прекрасной [**Ребекки Франкс**](https://www.google.com/search?q=Rebecca%20Franks&oq=Rebecca%20Franks&aqs=chrome.0.69i59l3j69i61.3582j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), вот видосик на [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/user/TheRiggaroo/search?query=constraint) канале.

З.Ы.Ы. Надеюсь все ясно расписал, будут вопросы, задавайте.

Comment: Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow. Хорошие ответы помогают разобраться в проблеме, вместо того чтобы дать готовое решение. Пожалуйста добавьте описание того что вы изменили в коде.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/taskView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_medium"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/rectangleNumber"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/rectangleNumber"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cvalView" />
```

Несколько комментариев к разметке в целом:
При использовании ConstraintLayout советую привязывать не к предыдущему элементу, а к тому, от которого действительно есть зависимость. То есть у Вас марджины выставлены для rectangleNumber, остальные элементы тогда привязываем к нему, а не друг к другу - это делает привязку более явной. Иначе теряется понимание того, какие отступы будут. Ну и желательно всегда делать привязку по крайней мере с трёх сторон.

Comment: Таким образом `TextView` будет центрирован, а мне нужно выравнивание по левому краю. Ведь там может быть и короткий текст из одного слова.

Comment: @AntonCharov попробуйте с гравити (ответ обновил)

Comment: @AntonCharov немного улучшил Вашу правку, попробуйте этот вариант

Answer (score 0):

Если в тексте используется /u0020 вместо пробела (Unicode Character SPACE) то данный символ не считается за пробел и перенос происходит по длине строки